# Difference in behaviour of CreateFile and open

Tags: c++, c, macos, winapi, unix

I am porting an application from Windows to Mac OS X. In the code given below, I open the given file for write. I observed that on Windows, it fails on second `OpenFileForWrite`. However on Mac OS X, it allows the same file to be opened for write using `OpenFileForWrite`. What is the reason for this difference?

Code:

```
//ON WINDOWS
typedef wchar_t * FileStr;
int OpenFileForWrite (const FileStr filename)
{   
    return OpenFile (filename, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS);
}

int OpenFile (const FileStr filename, ULong func, ULong mode, ULong flag)
{

    if(filehandle_) {
        Close ();
    }

    // Save the mode in which the file was opened
    openmode_ = mode;
    openfunc_ = func;
    openflag_ = flag;

   // open file
   filehandle_ = CreateFile (filename, func, mode, NULL, flag, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);

   //CASE : success to open file.. check for unicode file or not and return
   if ((filehandle_) && (filehandle_ != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)) {
       return 0;
   }

   filehandle_  = NULL;

   // not able to open file..set last error
   return GetLastError ();
}


//ON MAC OS X
typedef char * FileStr;
int OpenFileForWrite (const FileStr filename)
{   
    //read, write the file
    // no share
    // Open always
    return OpenFile (filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL);
}

int OpenFile (const FileStr filename, Long flag)
{

    if(fd_) {
        Close ();
    }

    openmode_   = flag;

    fd_ = open(filename, flag);

    //CASE : success to open file.. check for unicode file or not and return
    if (fd_ > 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // not able to open file..set last error
    return error;
}
```

Also, I want to know the equivalent of option `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` options on Mac OS X. Is there any way to achieve the behaviour of `FILE_SHARE_READ` and `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` using `open` function or any other system call?

Comment: Different operating systems have different system calls. OSX (like Linux and the BSDs) is [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) and so has the POSIX [`open`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) system call. Windows is using the [WIN32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa271855%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) API, and so have the [`CreateFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WIN32 function.

Comment: Also, on failure to open a file, you should check what the error was. On POSIX you check [`errno`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html) (and can print the error using [`perror`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html)). On Windows use [`GetLastError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You are right. I to want learn more about their differences. Can you tell me more about file sharing mode on Unix?

Comment: By default, POSIX systems doesn't lock files, you have to explicitly do that, and there are a few different ways of doing it. Just do a search for e.g. "posix file locking". That of course means that files by default are shared, and that two or more processes can both read *and* write to the same file. Simultaneous writing is not recommended though, you need to do some kind of [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) to synchronize the writes.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, you beat me to it; that's what I was going to write! I think you should put that as an answer, not a comment.